# How can I see the hierarchy of components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side application. I have several nested components inside of each other. Is there an easy way, without manually inspecting all components, to see what hierarchy of components I have? Ideally it would look like a list, for example:

- App

  - MainLayout

    - MyPage

But I can't find any documentation or StackOverflow questions about this.

Comment: There's another question similar to this one here on SO but from official Microsoft docs there isn't any possibility to have the tree.

Comment: Thanks Nicola. In that case, I think the current best solution is retrieving the parent inside of a component, and doing the same in the parent, etc.

Comment: There are no Parent or Controls properties unless you create them yourself.